# Sums of Egyptian Fractions of Minimal Length

Tags: egyptian-fractions

Let $\frac{a}{b}$
  and $\frac{p}{q}$
  be rational numbers in the interval $\left(0,1\right)$
  such that $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{p}{q}<1$, and such that: $$\frac{a}{b} = \frac{1}{u_{1}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{u_{M}}$$
$$\frac{p}{q} = \frac{1}{v_{1}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{v_{N}}$$
 are Egyptian fraction representations of minimal length, where, for any distinct $j,k$, we have that $u_{j}\neq u_{k}$, $v_{j}\neq v_{k}$, and that none of the $u_{j}$s is a $v_{k}$, and vice-versa.

I have two questions:

I. Is: $$\frac{1}{u_{1}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{u_{M}}+\frac{1}{v_{1}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{v_{N}}$$
 necessarily a minimal-length Egyptian fraction for $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{p}{q}$?

II. In case (I) is false, will my conclusion hold if I suppose further that all the $u_{m}$s and $v_{n}$s are positive integer powers of a fixed integer $\lambda\geq2$?

Comment: I understand that $u_k\neq v_j$ *even* for $j=k$, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, I guess so. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 2):

**I**

No. In fact, for any integer $n\ge 2$,
$$\frac1{n(n-1)}+\frac1n=\frac1{n-1}$$

Comment: @hardmath Denominators must be *different*.

Comment: Yeah. All of the denominators are different.

Comment: If all the denominators are different powers of $\lambda \ge 2$, then the "Egyptian fractions" considered are radix $\lambda$ expansions that terminate, and these are unique (so the minimality of any of these is automatic).

Comment: Huzzah! So, the radix expansions *do* actually have the same length as the minimal egyptian fraction length?

Comment: @MCS:  Yes, your intuition did not fail you there. Of course by "radix expansions ... length" here is meant the number of ones (equiv. nonzero place values) appearing in the expansion.